# WinForms Button: Autosize Maximumsize

Tags: c#, winforms, button, autosize

I want to add Buttons to a FlowLayoutPanel. The Buttons might contain longer texts with spaces between the words. The Buttons are Autosize=true and AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink. Further more I set the MaximumSize property to (maxwidth,0). maxwidth is the width of the panel. So the button does not grow too wide.

What I see is, that the widht of the Button is limited by the MaximumSize property, but when text wrapping occurs, the Button's height doesn't autosize to the height of the wrapped text. Is there a solution to that problem?

---

I also tried this manually sizing the button like this:

```
using (Graphics cg = this.CreateGraphics()) {
SizeF size = cg.MeasureString(button.Text, button.Font, 200);
  button.Width = (int)size.Width+20;
  button.Height = (int)size.Height+20;
  button.Text = someLongTextWithSpaces;
}
```

But please note that I added 20 to the calculated size. It's working, but is there a proper way to determin this additional size? Maybe 2x Padding + ?????

---

A few hours later...

I came to this version which seems to work quite fine.

```
using (Graphics cg = this.CreateGraphics()) {
  var fmt = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
  var prop = new Size(tableLayoutPanel1.Width - 20, 0);
  var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(button.Text, button.Font, prop, fmt);

  int border = button.Height - button.Font.Height;
  button.Width = (int)size.Width + border;
  button.Height = (int)size.Height + border;
  button.Text = someLongTextWithSpaces;
}
```

It seems that the initial button height is borders + the height the font. So I calculated the border subtracting button.Height-button.font.Height.

According to Hans, I now use the TextRenderer.MeasureText. I tested it without enabling VisualStyles and it worked fine. Any comments on that?

Comment: instead `maxwidth` (if You manually add this number) try this `FlowLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle.Width` (or however You called that panel). .... for example, in `Form_Resize` put code : `Button1.MaximumSize = New Size(FlowLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle.Width, 0)` (this is vb code, please convert him to c#).... I think this is c# code : `Button1.MaximumSize == new Size(FlowLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle.Width, 0);`

Comment: I also set the MaximumSize manually to a fixed value. The value is ok, only the height resizeing is not working. You can test that in the FormDesigner as well. Add an autosized button with grow/shring and a longer text with spaces. Set Maximum width smaller then the text. The button width get's limited, but it doesn't grow in height..

Comment: Why you added the +20?

Comment: @Aseem Gautam: Just guest a value for testing. Finding out the real value is the question.

Comment: You can use a dummy to find out the height of a line on your button by setting text to "X", then set it ti "X\r\nX". The difference is the height of __one line of button text__.

Comment: @TaW: I tried the way of create one Button with 1 line height and one with 2 line height. However, the height of the Button was calculated after adding the Button to the form, not immediately.

Comment: I would expect it to be calculated only during/after layout. But I think you can get away with making it invisible and even deleting it once you have the magic number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the initial button height is borders + the height the font. So I calculated the border subtracting button.Height-button.font.Height. (See the last block of my original post)

This also works with VisualStyles enabled/disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure that `button.Height-button.font.Height` is equal to calling `VisualStyleRenderer.GetBackgroundContentRectangle()`. My tests show that `button.Height-button.font.Height` returns large value for border than `VisualStyleRenderer.GetBackgroundContentRectangle()`. It depends on Dpi, font size and so on. For example with 96dpi and 8.25pt font size, your methods return **5px** as border and VisualStyles' method return **3px** as border!

Answer (score 3):

There is a proper way, but it isn't exactly very subtle.  Reverse-engineering it from the ButtonRenderer class source code, the Winforms class that draws the button text, you must use the TextRenderer class to measure the text.  And you must use the VisualStyleRenderer.GetBackgroundContentRectangle() method to obtain the effective drawing bounds.  Note that it is smaller than the button's Size because of the border and a margin that depends on the selected visual style.

Non-trivial problems are mapping a calculated content rectangle back to the outer button size and dealing with old machines that don't have visual styles enabled.  Sample code that appeared to arrive at the correct size:

```
    private static void SetButtonSize(Graphics gr, Button button) {
        VisualStyleElement ButtonElement = VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal;
        var visualStyleRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(ButtonElement.ClassName, ButtonElement.Part, 0);
        var bounds = visualStyleRenderer.GetBackgroundContentRectangle(gr, button.Bounds);
        var margin =  button.Height - bounds.Height;
        var fmt = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
        var prop = new Size(bounds.Width, 0);
        var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(button.Text, button.Font, prop, fmt);
        button.ClientSize = new Size(button.ClientSize.Width, size.Height - margin);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        using (var gr = this.CreateGraphics()) {
            SetButtonSize(gr, this.button1);
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Not extensively tested for corner cases, can't say I recommend this.

Comment: I created a new way calculating the border (see my post above). Do you think this is a suitable way? At least it worked for me with and wihtout VisualStyles enabled.

Comment: Hmm, magic numbers like "20" are never a good idea, they don't work when the video DPI changes.

Comment: Do you mean the "20" in "tableLayoutPanel1.Width - 20"?  I just don't want the button to fill out the complete width of tableLayoutPanel1. Ok, in reality the distance between the centered button end the sides is not 2x10 but 2x (10-bordersize). So unless the border is 10 or more, it should fit. Maybe I should use 2x(calculated border + something) and take that instead of "20".

Answer (score 0):

You should control the line breaks by adding newline characters in the text. Automatic text wrapping won't work with spaces alone:

```
button1.Text = "123232131232\r\nfgfdgfdgdfgdfgdf\r\nASDSADSDASD";
```

Or :

```
button1.Text = "123232131232" + Environment.NewLine + 
           "fgfdgfdgdfgdfgdf" + Environment.NewLine + "ASDSADSDASD";
```

If you'd rather get the automatic wrapping you could try to use `TextMeasure` to determine the height needed for the text and then set the button's height accordingly but that may need some extra attention..

But I suggest to consider using Labels instead. For a Label the wrapping works out of the box.. Huge Buttons with varying sizes are non-standard UI elements.